# How can I skip before_action CASClient::Frameworks::Rails::Filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I'm using:

```
gem 'rails', '5.1.7'
```

and

```
rspec (3.7.0)
```

I'm trying to write RSpec and I need to skip the before_action `CASClient::Frameworks::Rails::Filter`

I tried to do it in `before(:each)`

```
  before(:each) do
    controller.class.class_eval do
      skip_before_action CASClient::Frameworks::Rails::Filter
    end
  end
```

but the code gets executed many times and from 2nd time onward `CASClient::Frameworks::Rails::Filter` cannot be found since it will be  already removed by the first test case.

I want to do it using something similar to `allow(student1).to receive(:name) { 'John Smith'}` but I don't know how to do it.

How can I skip the before_action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubycas/rubycas-client/CASClient%2FFrameworks%2FRails%2FFilter.fake), the standard way to get around this in testing seems to be

```
before do
  CASClient::Frameworks::Rails::Filter.fake('homer')
end
```